# $vy^2=voy^2-2g(y-yo)$

Tags: kinematics, projectile

When I use the above equation compared to this equation $v_y$=$v_{oy}-gt$ I get the same answer but the $V_y^2 $always gets me a positive answer and a wrong direction.

For example if a ball landed 40 meters below its starting point the above equation when I plug everything in will give me let’s say 4 while the Vy will give me -4....their both same answers but different direction...why is this?

Idk calcus if you can leave it out that would be great

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you are standing on a cliff which is $15 \, \rm m$ high and you throw a ball up at a speed of $10 \, \rm m\,s^{-1}$.
Assume there is no air resistance, the acceleration of free fall is $10 \,\rm m\,s^{-2}$ downwards and $y_0=0$, ie the displacement of the ball at time $t=0$ is zero.

If you take up as the positive direction then $v_{\rm y0} = + 10,\, a = -10$ and $y = - 15$.

If you do the calculations you find that when

$t=0 \Rightarrow v_{\rm y0} = +10$ and $y = 0$ at the start

$t=1 \Rightarrow v_{\rm y} = 0$ and $y = +5$ the ball has reached its highest point

$t=2 \Rightarrow v_{\rm y} = -10$ and $y = 0$ the ball has returned to where it started and is moving with the same speed but going in the opposite direction.

$t=3 \Rightarrow v_{\rm y} = -20$ and $y = -15$ the ball has reached the bottom of the cliff.

See what happens when you put in a value for $y \,(= -15)$ at the bottom of the cliff and use $v_{\rm y}^2= v^2_{\rm y0} +2a(y-y_0)$ to find $v_{\rm y}$.

$v^2_{\rm y} = (+10)^2 + 2\,(-10)\, (-15) = +400 \Rightarrow v_{\rm y} = \pm 20$ and this is where you have made your mistake because you took the positive value of the velocity (ie the ball is moving up) rather than the negative value.
The positive value of $+20$ for the velocity would have occurred at a time $t=-1$ ie one second before you threw the ball but from the way the initial conditions were set.
This is an impossible solution to the problem.

Note that you get two values for $v_{\rm y} = \pm 10$ if you set $y=0$ into the equation $v_{\rm y}^2= v^2_{\rm y0} +2a(y-y_0)$ with the $+10$ value for the velocity occurring at $t=0$ and the $-10$ value occurring at $t=2$.

Doing your calculation by evaluating the time by using $y = v_{\rm y0}t + \frac 12at^2$  and then using $v_{\rm y} = v_{\rm yo} + at$ you will also reach a stage where you have to solve a quadratic equation in time and you quite correctly chose the positive value for the time $(t = +3)$ rather than the negative value (t=-1)$.

So the Mathematics (solving equations) gives you two values and you have to choose the correct value in terms of the problem in hand.